# Почему чекбокс не передает несколько значений

Tags: php, laravel

Моя проблема:есть несколько данных в таблице мне нужно чтобы в $_GET
записывались айди тех на которых стоит галочка но у меня выходит
значение только первой галочки

***форма***

```
 <form action="{{URL::to('othet_nn')}}" method="get" id="qwe">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="{{$oth->id}}">

             </form>
```

***контролер в котором я проверяю содержимость $_GET***

```
  public function chek(Request $request){
            dd($_GET);
            return view('admin.pages.othet_test');
        }
```

[image]если выбираю две галочки то выходит только "id" => "6" а должно быть столько id сколько галочек

[image][Если выбираю 2 галочку то проcто null

А мне нужно чтобы если допустим выбрали 2 галочки ты записывается id 
двух пользователей а не одного или вообще ноль

Comment: На форме видна только одна галочка. Откуда взяться остальным?

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки на сервер массива значений требуется указать в названии параметра, что это массив:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="{{$oth->id}}">
```